# Need help to find out the error of xml

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

Im using php and generating xml dynamically with codeigniter . Can somebody help me to find the error .PictureThumbnailURL node is not opening properly for the given values . This happens only for this single Product node(Second node in the quote) . I think the values makes the issue but i couldn't find the error. Thanks a lot .

```
<Product>
    <ProductCode>22352</ProductCode>
    <ProductName>DIY Wall Clock</ProductName>
    <Description>$23.90 for DIY Wall Clock + Delivery</Description>
    <ProductCategoryCode>307</ProductCategoryCode>
    <ProductCategoryName>Decor </ProductCategoryName>
    <ProductURL>http://www.url/deals/view/22352/9001591</ProductURL>
    <PictureThumbnailURL>http://url/images/deals/159569536568597.jpg</PictureThumbnailURL>
    <Currency>SGD</Currency>
    <Price>39.9</Price>
    <SalePrice>23.9</SalePrice>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <ProductCode>22337</ProductCode>
    <ProductName>Cacia Glass Table </ProductName>
    <Description>$79 for Cacia Glass Table  + Delivery</Description>
    <ProductCategoryCode>306</ProductCategoryCode>
    <ProductCategoryName>Furniture </ProductCategoryName>
    <ProductURL>http://url/deals/view/22337/9001591</ProductURL>
    PictureThumbnailURL>http://www.url/images/deals/527081231145166.jpg</PictureThumbnailURL>
    <Currency>SGD</Currency>
    <Price>131</Price>
    <SalePrice>79</SalePrice>
  </Product>
```

Comment: how do you generate in codeigniter?

Comment: check out the highlighting on your question

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Error

```
PictureThumbnailURL>http://www.url/images/deals/527081231145166.jpg</PictureThumbnailURL>
```

This should be

```
<PictureThumbnailURL>http://www.url/images/deals/527081231145166.jpg</PictureThumbnailURL>
```

You should realy have a Syntax Highlightning Programm.

Comment: Thanks Cristian . But the issue i have is this xml node generated every time with this error . Thats what i wanted to solve . Any ideas ?